# Android show MDWiki in WebView

Tags: android, android-webview, markdown

I need to open an MDWiki with a WebView.
So i load the index.html from the android_asset.
First error was that he didn't find config.json file. I created this myself. Then i had an error for favicon.png. I use a normal picture for this now.
But he still don't load the wiki.
I tried to load only the .md files. But than it is like loading it into a text editor.
There are some problems with loading .md files.
This is my code:

```
private WebView webView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowContentAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

This is the logcat:

[INFO:CONSOLE(1)] "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier", source: file:///android_asset/index.html#!index.md (1)
[INFO:CONSOLE(199)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'theme' of null", source: file:///android_asset/index.html#!index.md (199)
[INFO:CONSOLE(198)] "[FATAL] Timeout reached for done callback in stage: postgimmick. Did you forget a done() call in a .subscribe() ?", source: file:///android_asset/index.html#!index.md (198)
[INFO:CONSOLE(198)] "[FATAL] stage postgimmick failed running subscribed function: function (b){a(e);void 0!==window.localStorage.theme&&c||f(d),b()}", source: file:///android_asset/index.html#!index.md (198)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answered my own question.
I used cwac-anddown to read the files and make a string with HTML make up.
And a normal webview can open the string with LoadDataWithBaseURL function.
cwac-anddown is a library that converts markdown files to html strings. It uses NDK which should be installed before trying this.
https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-anddown
Here is how to install it or you can do it by AAR to.